# When will Deepin 15.11 support end?

Tags: linux

I will install Deepin 15.11 because the Deepin 20 is a beta version. But i can't find when will support end. I want install a stable version or other version like this.

Comment: Only the developer can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepin 15.11 is based on Debian Stretch, which has an expected EOL of 2020, or 2022 if Deepin 15.11 uses the LTS version of Debian Stretch.